# Speed up query on 100,000,000 rows

Tags: python, sqlite

I have 2 scripts. 1 to add data to SQLite database and one to query using 3 different queries. The database will have 100 million rows and 2 columns (average 50 characters per record).

Problem 1: Once I get to around 10 million each CSV file I add takes hours to import.

Problem 2: When I run the query script it takes in excess of 30 minutes to load. The actual query takes only seconds. Is there any better way of running this?

Input script :

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('Main_Database.db')

c = conn.cursor()

# c.execute('SELECT * FROM user_data')

# result = c.fetchall()

with open('my_list_2.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        try:
            l = line.split('\n')[0].split(':')
            # print(l[0])
            # print(l[1])
            c.execute("INSERT INTO user_data VALUES (?,?)", (l[0], l[1]))
        except IndexError:
            pass
        except sqlite3.IntegrityError:
            pass
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Query script :

```
import sqlite3
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date
import re
import csv
import numpy as np

conn = sqlite3.connect('Main_Database.db')

c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("SELECT * FROM user_data")

items = c.fetchall()

exact_match_mail = 'abc123'
#method = 'method 1'

word_match_mail = 'hot'
#method = 'method 2'

method = 'method 3'
word_match_mail_one = 'hot'
word_match_mail_two = 'chocolate'

L = []
if method == 'method 1':
    for x, y in items:
        if x == exact_match_mail:
            print('there is an exact match to the email: ', x)
            L.append(x)

elif method == 'method 2':
    for x, y in items:
        if word_match_mail in re.split("@|_", x):
            print('Partial match based on one word found in the email: ', x)
            L.append(x)

elif method == 'method 3':
    for x, y in items:
        if word_match_mail_one in re.split("@|_", x) and word_match_mail_two in re.split("@|_", x):
            print('Partial match based on two words found in the email: ', x)
            L.append(x)

a = input('press any key to export result to a csv file')

if a != np.nan:
    f = open('saved_emails.csv', 'a', encoding='UTF8')
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    now = datetime.now()
    current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    today = date.today()
    d1 = today.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
    row = "********* report "+d1+" "+current_time+" **************"
    writer.writerow([row])
    row = "method used for this query is: " + method
    writer.writerow([row])
    row = "emails obtained are: "
    writer.writerow([row])
    for x in L:
        writer.writerow([x])
    f.close()

conn.commit()

conn.close()
```

Comment: You don't do bulk import like that. But more importantly, it sounds like sqlite is not what you should be using. Do these files contain sequence data?

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you use a database but don't benefit from the features it provides.

1. Inserting a huge number of records one by one is inefficient.
   Databases always provide `import` and `dump` features.
   Here you can use `import` and provide a flat file : text or csv for example.
2. A database is designed to store and search data.
   Here it looks like you just use it as a dummy storage.
   You request all the data then select "by hand".
   You have SQL (Structured Query Language) that allows to perform simple and complex selections and diverse operations on your data.
   `SELECT * FROM user_data WHERE ...`

Databases are very powerful. You can even create indexes on your columns for more performance.

Don't worry. 100 000 000 rows is not so much.
Especially if rows are composed of only two columns (as in your example).
It should still work on a single machine.